# fadeout from one table and fadein to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have two `<ul>`:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        // I show the parameters of the row
    </li>
</ul>


<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">
        // I show the parameters of the row
    </li>
</ul>
```

when the user press the parameters of the row of `sortable1`, I want it to fadeout and fadein to `sortable2`.

pay attention that in fadein I have to change `<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">` and `<li class="ui-state-default">` to: `<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">` and `<li class="ui-state-highlight">`.

I tried to define in my `application.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').fadeOut(function() {
       $(this).closest('ul#sortable2').fadeIn(3000);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.highlight_on_success').bind("ajax:success", function(){

      $(this).closest('li').fadeOut(3000);    

    });
});
```

but it doesn't work.

this is my `index.html.erb`:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id ="mydiv">

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable"> 
  <% @tasks_worker_todo.each do |task| %>
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <%= best_in_place task, :done, :classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox,collection: %w[False True] %> | 
            <%= task.admin_mail %> | 
            <%= task.task %>
        </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>


<br><br>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <% @tasks_worker_done.each do |task| %>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">
            <%= best_in_place task, :done,:classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox, collection: %w[False True] %>| 
            <%= task.admin_mail %> | 
            <%= task.task %>
        </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#sortable1").click(function(){
         jQuery("#sortable1").fadeOut(500);
         jQuery("#sortable2").fadeIn(500);
    });

    jQuery("#sortable2").click(function(){
         jQuery("#sortable2").fadeOut(500);
         jQuery("#sortable1").fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you.. I think I do something wrong:
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.highlight_on_success').bind("ajax:success", function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#sortable1").click(function(){
         jQuery("#sortable1").fadeOut(500);
         jQuery("#sortable2").fadeIn(500);
      });

      jQuery("#sortable2").click(function(){
         jQuery("#sortable2").fadeOut(500);
         jQuery("#sortable1").fadeIn(500);
      });
    });
  });
});

Comment: Don't write jQuery(document).ready(function()) twice. Remove the inner one and it should work.

Comment: ok, thank you.. but all the ul fadeout, I want that only the pressed il will fadeout.

Comment: and what do you want to fadeIn then?

Comment: just the il that is pressed. based on your solution, I tried something like: jQuery("#sortable1#ui-state-default").click(function(){
         jQuery("#sortable1#ui-state-default").fadeOut(500);
         jQuery("#sortable2#ui-state-highlight").fadeIn(500);

Comment: just give the space after #sortable1 and #sortable2 respectively so it will be like this  jQuery("#sortable1 .ui-state-default").click(function(){ jQuery("#sortable1 .ui-state-default").fadeOut(500); jQuery("#sortable2 .ui-state-highlight").fadeIn(500);

Comment: of course, but I'm sorry, it doesn't work: $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.highlight_on_success').bind("ajax:success", function(){
      jQuery("#sortable1 .ui-state-default").click(function(){
         jQuery("#sortable1 .ui-state-default").fadeOut(500);
         jQuery("#sortable2 .ui-state-highlight").fadeIn(500);
      });

         jQuery("#sortable2 .ui-state-highlight").click(function(){
         jQuery("#sortable2 .ui-state-highlight").fadeOut(500);
         jQuery("#sortable1 .ui-state-default").fadeIn(500);
      });
  });
});

Comment: Can you tell me which function is this which you are binding : ajax:success

Comment: maybe we have to move this discussion to chat?
<span class='best_in_place highlight_on_success2' id='best_in_place_tasksadmin_1_done' data-url='/tasksadmins/1' data-object='tasksadmin' data-collection='["False","True"]' data-attribute='done' data-type='checkbox'>True</span>

Comment: You don't have the previlige to chat right now .

which function is this which you are binding : ajax:success

Comment: that is: https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#ajax-success-callback

(if I alert a message, it works, so I think this is not the problem)

Comment: can you put all your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and save it and give me the link to check it.

Comment: but in order to ajax_success works, I have the directories of that. I will try something else.. please wait..